# Is reciting 'salat o salam' in mehfil(gathering) allowed in Islam?

Tags: quran, source-identification, sahih-bukhari, sects

There has been much debate among deobandi and baralvi of salat o salam, but both sect belong to Sunni. However there are one sect who say companions of prophet Muhammad(PBUH) use to recall salat o salam.

**Question:**

is it true and is it permissible to call mehfil(gathering) in which all people gather and read salat o salam and other verses from Qur'an?

Comment: describing more about that 'salat o salam' or telling exactly what they recite would help a lot. Also try explaining the ritual in detail... **also ask them on what basis(hadith) are they performing those** that would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: plz think of providing more detail....

Answer (score 4):

Well in this general question there is nothing wrong with reading quran in a gathering. The salat & salam is also perfectly fine and it is also presribed to do so. Also, doing that in a gathering is not necessarily related to those 2 sects, because others do it also. That being said, it is also okay because the reason for that is so other people may also *benefit* from that. Especially on thursday night (which in islam is friday) it is recommended to read surah kahf and also durood on the prophet SAWS.

Sayyiduna Rasoolullah (sallal laahu alaihi wasallam) said, “Increase your reading of the Durood Shareef during the nights and days of Jummah. Certainly Durood Shareef is presented to me”. (Jaami’us Sagheer)

Sayyiduna Abu Hurairah (radi Allahu anhu) narrates that Sayyiduna Rasoolullah (sallal laahu alaihi wasallam) said, “Whosoever performs the Salaatul Asar on Jummah, remains at the same placewithout moving, and recites the following Durood eighty times, ‘Allahumma salli ala Sayyiduna Muhammaddin Nabiyyil Ummi wa ala ahlihi wasallam,’ eighty years of his sins are forgiven and on his record of deeds, he will receive reward (Thawaab) equivalent to eighty years of Salaah.”

> On the day of Qiyamah the person closest to me will be the one who has sent the most Durood unto me. ” ([TIRMIZI](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/3/32))
>
> On Fridays, send Durood abundantly on me, as it is presented before me. ” ([ABU DAWUD](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/116))

“Whoever recites Durood at my grave, I hear it myself. And whoesoever recites it from a distance, Angels present them to me.” (BAIHAQI)

“For the reciter of durood, Allah sends 70 blessings on him and the angels make dua for him 70 times.”(TABRANI)

Almighty Allah says:

> “Surely Allah and His Angels send blessings on the Holy Prophet (Sallal Laahu Alaihi Wasallim). O you who believe! Send Blessings (Durood) and Salutations (Salaams) on the Prophet with worthy Salutation”.([Surah al-Ahzab: 56](http://legacy.quran.com/33/56))

Hazrat Anas (radi Allahu anhu) narrates that Sayyiduna Rasoolullah (Sallal Laahu Alaihi Wasallim) said: “He who reads a single Durood upon me, Almighty Allah blesses him ten times, ten of his sins are forgiven, and he is increased ten times in stages (internally). (Mishkaat)

further link:
http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askmufti/45591